# After sex shall we touch our son without Ghusl[Bath]

Tags: sex, ghusl

I'm listening this from my elder's that don't touch or lift the children's without ghusl [taking bath] if couples had sex.
But I have one year old boy, Is this right to touch or feed him milk without taking bath If we had sex or Ghusl is Must to touch or feed to the child.
Can any one pls clear this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in islam , Everything is allowed, Unless it is proved haram. So as there is no such thing as you mentioned (that you cannot touch your baby after sex) then it is perfectly fine to touch him, there is nothing wrong in it. Those who claim that it is wrong, ask them to bring Evidence from Quran or sunnah, as they cannot produce such evidence from Quran and sunnah, they are lying, as they just heard from here and there and told it to you, without any verification.

Even from Islamic point of view, you cannot touch Quran or pray, during state of janabah (after sex) otherwise,you can do everything.